# Bash - problem with splitting string from mysql-client parse in Ubuntu 18

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, bash, ubuntu

I have a script, that accesses a central database server (mariadb 10.2 on CentOS 7.7) to get a random database entry.

```
#!/bin/bash

function getrandom()
{
     mysql -h 11.22.33.44 -P 3306 -u usr -p password -D dbExample -e "SELECT ip, host FROM hosts ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"
}

entry=$(getrandom)
```

Database has entries, ie:

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | ip      | host         |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  2 | 8.8.8.8 | facebook.com |
|  3 | 1.1.1.1 | google.de    |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

So, the mysql select should get the following string:

```
ip host 8.8.8.8 facebook.com
```

or

```
ip host 1.1.1.1 google.de
```

So the next step I wanted to do is to split the string by ' ' into an array and write [2] and [3] into vars for further processing.

On another Centos 7.7 Server, this is absolutely no problem with:

```
IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< $entry
```

or even

```
ip="$(cut -d' ' -f3 <<< "$entry")"
host="$(cut -d' ' -f4 <<< "$entry")"
```

However, when trying to execute the script on ubuntu 18.04, nothing of the solution for the splits seems to work. I use mysql-client-core-10.1 for the mysql call. After some unsucessful debugging attempts, I went back to the parse for the $entry var.

Here, I noticed when echoing $entry, the full string is returned:

```
echo $entry

returns: ip host 1.1.1.1 google.de
```

When echoing "$entry", only the first two elements are returned:

```
echo "$entry"

returns: ip host
```

I think, this is the source of the problem here, but I do not understand, why this is working under CentOS.

Continuing with my script, the splits do nothing. I tried:

```
IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< $entry
```

saves: "ip host" in $ADDR

```
IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$entry"
```

saves: "ip host" in $ADDR

```
ip="$(cut -d' ' -f3 <<< "$entry")"
host="$(cut -d' ' -f4 <<< "$entry")"
```

saves: "ip host 8.8.8.8 facebook.com" in both variables (and yes, this actually worked with the quotes, even though this should make "$(cut -d' ' -f4 <<< " into a string from my understanding)

```
ip="$(cut -d' ' -f3 <<< $entry)"
host="$(cut -d' ' -f4 <<< $entry)"
```

saves: "ip host 8.8.8.8 facebook.com" in both variables

```
ip=$(cut -d' ' -f3 <<< $entry)
host=$(cut -d' ' -f4 <<< $entry)
```

saves: "ip host 8.8.8.8 facebook.com" in both variables

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Edit:

Output from `getrandom | od -t x1`:

```
0000000 69 70 09 68 6f 73 74 0a 38 2e 38 2e 38 2e 38 09
0000020 66 61 63 65 62 6f 6f 6b 2e 63 6f 6d 0a
0000035
```

Thank you, I think I'm back on track :)

```
i  p  <tab> h  o  s  t <newline> 8  .  8  .  8  .  8 <tab>
f  a  c  e  b  o  o  k  .  c  o  m  <newline>
```

Comment: What does `echo -e "$entry"` output?

Comment: echo -e "$entry" returns: 8.8.8.8 facebook.com

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like there is some garbage between the two substrings: `ip host` and `8.8.8.8 facebook.com`.

Comment: Add the output of `getrandom | od -t x1` to your question

Answer (score 0):

There were tabs and newline ascii signs in the returned value of the mysql client. I removed them with:

```
entry=$(echo "${entry//$'\t'/','}")
entry=$(echo "${entry/$'\n'/','}")
```

After that, the hexdump returned:

```
0000000 69 70 2c 68 6f 73 74 2c 38 2e 38 2e 38 2e 38 2c
0000020 66 61 63 65 62 6f 6f 6b 2e 63 6f 6d 0a
0000035
```

From there, it was the same as on CentOS:

```
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$entry"
ip=${array[2]}
host=${array[3]}
```

Echo returns `1.1.1.1` in $ip and `google.de` in $host.

Thank you stephanmg and oguz ismail for pointing me in the right direction! =)

Sure there is a smoother way to remove tab and newline with sed, but I could not get it to work, so for now there is this awkward solution.

Comment: You can use `tr -d '\t'`and `tr -d '\n'`.